# Missing SAP assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, saprfc, sap-dotnet-connector

I am trying to set up connection between SAP and .NET via [RFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Function_Call). SAP provides the .NET library *nco3* to make a connection.

When I compile the application, it says missing assemblies, even though they are imported. You can see this on the picture:

[image]

And assemblies

[image]

The code does not appear with red lines

[image]

Two important libraries are imported, *sapnco* and *sapnco_utils*. Why can I not compile the application?

Comment: what framework version are you targeting? full or client?

Comment: Well, the error clearly says you need `System.Web`. You might need to change the target to be able to add that.

Comment: .Net framework 4 client profile. @Jester Where it says I need `System.Web`?

Comment: The first highlighted message in your first picture? Also you might be having architecture issues (`AMD64` vs `x86`).

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28478393/edit). Thanks in advance.

Comment: (For search engine visitors: [.NET assembly / assemblies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_(CLI)) (compiled code library), not [assembly language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You compile for the x86 architecture, but you have referenced x64 SAP libraries.

Use the proper versions of the *sapnco* and *sapnco_utils* libraries. You need to create an x86 and x64 configuration for solution. Then link the proper library based on the configuration you choose. I use this in the project file:

```xml
<Reference Include="sapnco" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
  <HintPath>..\Libs\sapnco\x86\sapnco.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="sapnco" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
  <HintPath>..\Libs\sapnco\x64\sapnco.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="sapnco_utils" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
  <HintPath>..\Libs\sapnco\x86\sapnco_utils.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="sapnco_utils" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
  <HintPath>..\Libs\sapnco\x64\sapnco_utils.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Generally, I need to also mark the assembly as 'Copy local' to true. My experiments with library installation to the [GAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache) was not successful.

Comment: And if you run web application in IISExpress, you must switch to x86. ;-)